# How to convert Rotated Polar grid raster to Non Rotated Polar Raster?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-desktop

I have a RCM data which is in rotated Polar system , I want it to convert into non-rotated polar RCM. How can i do this things ? Please give some guidance

Comment: What's RCM? Can you write out and include a link, please?  What GIS software do you have available to try and do this?

Comment: I want to use RegCM4 and here is like for that RCM http://cordex-ea.climate.go.kr/main/modelsPage.do and I am trying to extract from ArcMap10.

Comment: @whuber gave a possible workflow: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29157/how-can-i-convert-geomagnetic-coordinates-to-geographic-coordinates-without-doin/29165#29165